# Find missing assemblies in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2013, assembly-references

I downloaded a VS2013 project from a Git repo. The repo does not include the assembly references inside it. However, I have the SDK that contains all of the references I need for the project. The problem is that the path for the references is empty. Currently I'm having to remove and re add each assembly one by one and it is wasting too much time.

Is there a way to set a path to the folder that contains all the references and have the VS project find and update them automatically?

Comment: `.csproj` is an human-readable xml file. try open it in text editor, find section where dlls are referenced and paste the path to your folder

Comment: Yeah that seemed to do the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like the project expects the references to be added to GAC.